# Make a combobox react to a click but do not show the dropdown section

Tags: vb.net, combobox, click

I have large form of combobox's (about 65 of them). Depending on the permissions of the user I would like the comboboxes to react differently.

For one level I would like the combobox to react as normal, show the list, allow changes etc.

For another level I would the combo to react to the click, but not show the dropdown menu and trigger different code.

I can't use the .enable property because I still need clicks from the lower level user to trigger something. I've "e.cancel" in previous code but the click event on a combo box doesn't seem to like it.

```
Error   BC30456 'cancel' is not a member of 'EventArgs'
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: You could use [GetComboBoxInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) to get the handle of the DropDownList and manage the DropDown assigning the handle to a [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow) class. Then call `[NativeWindow].DestroyHandle()` when the User *qualifications* don't meet your criteria. When the ComboBox Button is clicked, the `Click` event is raised anyway. This all, of course, if these are WinForms ComboBoxes. You didn't mention the UI framework.

Comment: You can't set e.Cancel in any event handler you want. Only those where the e parameter is type CancelEventArgs. In this case, I can't currently test this but I think that you can handle the DropDown event and set the Dropped Down property to False.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  That would show the DropDown for a moment, but you should probably `BeginInvoke()` it. -- Why do I get a notification, since you didn't `@` me?

Comment: A combination of both your comments has made this work. Thanks for this.